# Single word for wrong choice of words explaining situation/something wrongly but unintentionally

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word to imply that someone **unintentionally** chose the wrong words to describe/explain something/situation, which led to unpleasant consequences?

Example: He (the requested word) when talking about his colleagues.

Comment: If you are claiming that the speaker unintentionally chose the wrong word then you are *implying* it. If you are guessing that they chose the wrong word then you are *inferring* it. I'll not change it so you may make the point on your own.  A good phrase is *has a tin ear* for the word choice to imply a tone deafness of meaning or propriety.

Comment: @Elliot I apologize for not fully understanding your reply. Nevertheless, would you take my example in the question and rewrite it to indicate that I know for sure he unintentionally chose the wrong words?

Comment: I have made your requested change. You may edit the question with a fuller example or story to help us with additional ideas and context. I'm still thinking.

Comment: “ . . . misspoke”

Comment: @Elliot I edited my question to show that this unintentional mistake led to unpleasant consequences.

Comment: I guess "malapropism" isn't quite right because it doesn't include negative consequences? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malapropism

Comment: I don't think there's likely to be an ***intransitive*** verb for the generic activity OP describes here. But natural transitive usages include *He **misrepresented / mischaracterised** his colleagues when talking about them.*